# Intercept websocket and append a new token with NGINX

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy

before i was doing this proxy

```
location /ws/streams/ {
  rewrite \/ws\/streams\/(\d+) /streams/$1?token=TOKEN break;
  proxy_pass https://www.stream.com;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
}
```

but now I need the token to be dynamic (it expires every hour)

I need to somehow get that token and append it in that TOKEN variable. This new token is requested through a POST request using 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' as 'Content-Type'

If someone could help me I would really appreciate it

Thanks in advance